# how to hide all right siblings with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, siblings

```
$(this).parent().next().css('display','none');
```

The above only hides the sibling right next to the current one.

If there are multiple ones,will fail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use [`nextAll()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/nextAll)

```
$(this).parent().nextAll().css('display','none');
```

or even better:

```
$(this).parent().nextAll().hide()
```